# Swift Codable: How do I make multiple objects from embedded data

Tags: swift, codable

Say I have JSON like this:

```
    ["conferences": <__NSArrayI 0x60c00002f720>(
    {
        alias = Conference1;
        divisions =     (
                    {
                alias = "Division 1";
                id = "b95cd27d-d631-4fe1-bc05-0ae47fc0b14b";
                name = "Division 1";
                teams =             (
                                    {
                        alias = OXC;
                        id = "768c92aa-75ff-4a43-bcc0-f2798c2e1724";
                        market = East;
                        name = Rams;
                        references =                     (
                                                    {
                                id = Rams;
                                origin = gsis;
                            }
                        );

                    {
                        alias = AXC;
                        id = "768c92aa-75ff-4a43-bcc0-f2798c2e1724";
                        market = East;
                        name = Platypus;
                        references =                     (
                                                    {
                                id = Platypus;
                                origin = gsis;
                            }
                        );

                    },
{
           alias = "Division 2";
                id = "b95cd27d-d631-4fe1-bc05-0ae47fc0b14b";
                name = "Division 2";
                teams =             (
                                    {
                        alias = NXC;
                        id = "768c92aa-75ff-4a43-bcc0-f2798c2e1724";
                        market = West;
                        name = Ants;
                        references =                     (
                                                    {
                                id = Ants;
                                origin = gsis;
                            }
                        );

    {
                        alias = QXC;
                        id = "768c92aa-75ff-4a43-bcc0-f2798c2e1724";
                        market = West;
                        name = Bulls;
                        references =                     (
                                                    {
                                id = Bulls;
                                origin = gsis;
                            }
                        );

                    },
}]
```

I'm at a lost as to how to create an object that contains the team data but also the Conference and Division alias.

I started down this path but this seems like it'll just basically dump all the json onto the object. I don't want that overhead obviously.

```
struct Team:Codable {

    var arrConference:[Conference]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case arrConference = "conferences"
    }

    struct Conference:Codable {

        var conferenceName:String
        var conferenceID:String

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case conferenceName = "alias"
            case conferenceID = "id"
        }
    }

}
```

I guess I am stuck thinking in an old way, but how do you enumerate through the data with a codable?

Comment: This isn't JSON. It looks like the `description` output of a Dictionary with embedded NSArrays. Codable can definitely address this issue, but we'll need to see the actual JSON. It's not quite clear what you want the final data structure to look like. From your Swift, it looks like you want one Team to have multiple Conferences, which seems backwards.

Comment: As already stated, do not include the output of printing a parsed JSON response. Rather, simply parse the network response as `String`, which will give you the raw JSON response and include that in your question.

Comment: Not related to your question but `conferenceName` is redundant as well as conferenceID. I suggest naming it only `name` and `id`. It is already implied as being conference name by being name a property of conference structure. Btw why not simply conferences instead of arrConference? You wouldn't even need the CodingKeys declaration for Team

Comment: Your printout looks like you already went down the evil `JSONSerialization` route. This will mean you are bound to interpret your result riddled with optionals and `Any`-casts, this is hell to do in Swift and it is why `Codable` was invented where all the casting happens in one fell swoop. This will allow you to iterate much more quickly over the things you are interested in. If this looks like "too much overhead" you are stuck with something more ancient, I but would advise to measure the overhead before you assume bad things about it.

Comment: @Patru ~ you're right, which is why I am looking to switch to Codable. I was able to do that and the resulting object makes sense.